# Impact of changing github username on signing into a website with github

Tags: github

I signed up to a website with my Github account (the link read something like, "Sign in with Github"). I wish to change my Github username, and am curious whether altering the username will affect my "relationship" with that website--if I'll be able to sign into the site as normally, etc? Also curious, if yes or no, why so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is Off-topic question:

You have to understand how authorization works behind the `Sign in with Github`.

Github use oauth  authentication for the particualar user can sign in with particual app.

When you click on the first time "`Sign up with Github`" that app receives `access_token`.

Next time you login it'll check against that and log you in.